# PLSQL with java, when I run the program on java it doesn't react

Tags: java, sql, plsql

I have a function that picks a facility, gets its capacity and searches for the ships that will stop on that facility, and it will calculate the remaining capacity of that facility by the occupied ships:

```
create or replace function getShipAreaByDate(vFacility  varchar, currentDate  Date, maxDate  Date)
    RETURN number
is
    area         number;
    contagem     number;
    vLength      Ship.length%type;
    vWidth       Ship.width%type;
    vShipArea    number;
    areaFacility FACILITY.capacity%type;
    cDate        Date := currentDate;

BEGIN
    select f.CAPACITY
    into   areaFacility
    from   FACILITY f
    where  f.FACILITYID = 8;

    area := 0;

    while cDate != maxDate
    LOOP
        select count(s.WIDTH)
        into   contagem
        from   SHIP s
               inner join CARGOMANIFEST cm
                     on s.VEHICLEID = cm.VEHICLEID
        where  cm.CARGOMANIFESTDATE = TO_DATE(currentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        and cm.FACILITYID = vFacility;

        if(contagem != 0) THEN
            select s.WIDTH
            into   vWidth
            from   SHIP s
                   inner join CARGOMANIFEST cm
                         on s.VEHICLEID = cm.VEHICLEID
            where  cm.CARGOMANIFESTDATE = TO_DATE(currentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            and    cm.FACILITYID = vFacility;

            select s.LENGTH
            into   vLength
            from   SHIP s
                   inner join CARGOMANIFEST cm
                         on s.VEHICLEID = cm.VEHICLEID
            where  cm.CARGOMANIFESTDATE = TO_DATE(currentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            and    cm.FACILITYID = vFacility;

            vShipArea := vLength * vWidth;

            areaFacility := areaFacility - vShipArea;
            area := areaFacility;
        END IF;

        cDate := currentDate + 1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(areaFacility);

    END LOOP;

    return(area);
END;
/
```

When I try to run in java the program doesn't even react here's the code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM-dd-yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10 - 1); // <-- months start
    // at 0.
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    java.sql.Date dateI = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10 - 1); // <-- months start
    // at 0.
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);

    java.sql.Date dateF = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    CallableStatement cstmt = connection.getConnection().prepareCall("{? = call getShipAreaByDate(?,?,?)}");

    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
    cstmt.setString(2,"10");
    cstmt.setDate(3,dateI)  ;
    cstmt.setDate(4,dateF);

    cstmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Value:" + cstmt.getInt(1));
```

Comment: And what does "doesn't even react" mean?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the PL/SQL function works as expected? By the way, you don't need two queries of `ship` to get length and width. You can just `select s.width, s.length into vWidth, vlength from ship`. ('length' is a reserved word in SQL so not ideal as a column name.)

Comment: You may have a problem in your loop.  `while cDate != maxDate` suggests you want to increment and use `cDate` in the loop.  Try changing `cDate := currentDate + 1;` to `cDate := cDate + 1;`.  Then use `cDate` within the loop, not `currentDate`.

Comment: I would reconsider the logic you used in the loop.  We can use a single query to calculate `area` for all days in the range without a loop.  Also, what is the significance of facility 8?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first obvious issue is the infinite loop.  It's easy to see how that might cause an "I have no idea what it's doing" reaction.  `cDate` will never reach `maxDate`, unless `maxDate` happens to be just `currentDate + 1`;  `cDate := cDate + 1;` should help with that issue.